# awk a number, character, then the same number

Tags: regex, awk

I have a column of values where the field begins with n/n: and where n is a number between 0 and 20.

Other columns also contain "n/n:" information; I only want to filter based on a single specific column.

"n/n:" can be a combination of any pair of numbers between 0 and 20 (ex. 0/1:, 1/1:, 1/19:, 19/19:)

I would like to filter lines in the file where the first and second n are the same number in the column of interest (0/0, 1/1,... 20/20).

Rather than do this once for each combination of numbers (each iteration would take a long time):

```
awk '$col !~ /^n\/n:/' file > filtered.file
```

... I'm hoping there's a more concise, better way.

An example of the file

```
 1/1: 0/1: a
 1/2: 1/1: b
 0/1: 2/2: c
 3/3: 0/2: d
 0/2: 0/1: e
```

Desired output, filtered based on col2

```
 1/1: 0/1: a
 3/3: 0/2: d
 0/2: 0/1: e
```

Comment: From your update, it seems you want to get rid of `n/n` on column 2 and retain `n/m`.

Comment: Yes, I only want to remove the line if "n/n:" is 1/1:, 2/2:, etc and occurs in column 2. If if occurs in other columns (like in rows 1 and 4 in the example), that is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

**UPDATED**

```
$ awk -v col=2 '{split($col,a,"[/:]")} a[1]!=a[2]' file

 1/1: 0/1: a
 3/3: 0/2: d
 0/2: 0/1: e
```

Comment: Hi @karakfa

I've revised my example input-output file. The string contain a ":" at the end and it's important the file be filtered using the second column.

Comment: @karafka - follow up question; how could I keep lines where a[1]!=a[2] AND lines when "n/n:" = "0/0:"   ?

Comment: I guess you mean `OR`, so `a[1]!=a[2] || $col=="0/0:"`